# How to list Table Names from SQliteConnection c# Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to return a list of table names in an sqlite database but am unsure how, I cannot seem to find a solution.

```
        public List<string> GetTableNames()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "cmp_mobile_database.db")))
            {
                return connection.//Somthing Here???
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLite Exception", e.Message);
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Its a little strange you have business requirement to list tables for a mobile app.. also maybe something like this `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'`

Comment: Its for debugging so i Know the tables exist and have been created correctly.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7 this may help